# Role of additional groups for linux users

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to know the difference between the primary group and the additional for a user in Linux

For example, by adding a user to some groups, does he gain some priviliedges?

Furthermore, when I try to change the primary group for a user, by typing the following command:

```
sudo usermod -g maingroup user
```

Then, by typing the command `id`, I still get the original group as the `gid`, is that that normal?

Thank all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user can be a member of many groups, but only one primary group. This group will be associated with the user in the respect of new files being created (the group ownership will be the primary group). The same with process ownership of the new processes.

The secondary groups grant permissions.

As for the second part of your question, take a look at `man usermod`:

> -g, --gid GROUP
>
> The group name or number of the user's new **initial login group**. The group must exist.
>
> Any file from the user's home directory owned by the previous primary group of the user will be owned by this new group.
>
> The group ownership of files outside of the user's home directory must be fixed manually.

I guess what you need to do to see any effects is to log out and log back in. The same applies to any new group memberships.